# SVN ignore two folder with a single command line

Tags: svn, svnignore

```
svn propset svn:ignore bin .
```

The above command used to add a single directory to the ignore list.

repeating the same command to another directory want work. It's like removing the old directory from the list and adds the new one.

Also, `propedit` didn't work for me.

I want to add two folders (gen and bin) to the ignore list in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention some property value also along with the command.

`svn propset PROPNAME [PROPVAL | -F VALFILE] PATH...`

You can apply the property to multiple folders in one command as follows:

`svn propset svn:ignore some_property_value bin gen`

Just put the required directory names at the end of the above command.